# Escaping in makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, escaping

I'm trying to do this in a makefile and it fails horribly:

```
M_ARCH := $(shell g++ -dumpmachine | awk '{split($1,a,"-");print a[1]}')
```

do you know why? I guess it has to do with escaping, but what and where?

Comment: How does it fail? What error messages does it produce? What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

It's the dollar sign, in makefiles you'll have to type `$$` to get a single dollar sign:

```
M_ARCH := $(shell g++ -dumpmachine | awk '{split($$1,a,"-");print a[1]}')
```

Comment: Yeah, make is a total waste of money: you have to put two `$` to get one.

Comment: @PavelShved I've never once paid for make. :)

Comment: For anyone finding this answer as part of a search, there are also problems with '#' characters that are taken as the start of comments. For these, you should escape with a backslash: "\#".

Answer (score 18):

Make is quite lispy when you get down to it. Here's a non-awk version that does the same thing:

```
space := $() #

M_ARCH := $(firstword $(subst -,$(space),$(shell g++ -dumpmachine)))

all:
    $(info $(M_ARCH))
```