# how do I use pipes in a makefile shell command?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I have the following code snippet in a Makefile which always fails unless I remove the references to sed & grep below.

```
TAB=$(shell printf "\t")
all: abstract.tsv
      $(shell cut -d "${TAB}" -f 3 abstract.tsv | sed "s/^\s*//" | \
        sed "s/\s*$//" | grep -v "^\s*$" | sort -f -S 300M | \
        uniq > referenced_images.sorted.tsv)
```

This is the error I get:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382764/escaping-in-makefile

Comment: Just FYI, the two invocations of sed and one of grep can be combined into one instance of sed: `sed -ne '/^\s*$$/!{s/^\s*//;s/\s*$$//;p;}'` The initial pattern keeps space-only, and empty lines from being modified or displayed. (I've doubled the $s for make's benefit, of course.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One error is coming from `sed`.  When you write:

```
sed "s/\s*$//"
```

make expands the variable `$/` to an empty string, so sed is missing a delimiter.  Try:

```
sed "s/\s*$$//"
```

Using `$"` is causing the same problem in `grep`.  Use `grep -v "^\s*$$"` instead.