# Makefile $(command) not working but `command` did

Tags: git, makefile, backticks

The thing is when I was writing a Makefile for my project, when I needed to detect the current branch name, in a make rule I did this :

```
check_branch:
    if [ "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" == "master" ]; then \
    echo "In master"
    else \
    echo "Not in master"; \
    fi
```

When I called make check_branch, the **"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"** didn't work, it returned "" empty string. 
But instead when I changed **$()** to **` `**, it worked perfectly.

```
check_branch:
    if [ "`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`" == "master" ]; then \
    echo "In master"
    else \
    echo "Not in master"; \
    fi
```

Why is $() not working but `` did? Only for the "git" command.

Note that in my Makefile, I used **$()** normally in many rules.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please see: [Escaping in a Makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382764/escaping-in-makefile).  The issue is that the `$` (dollar sign) is special to `make`.  If you use a double dollar, it should work.

Comment: You should also take care to make sure you are in a directory in the `git` hierarchy.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Inside recipes you have to escape dollar signs in order to get them interpreted by the shell. Otherwise, Make treats `$(git ...)` as a built-in command or a variable and tries to evaluate it (of course, unsuccessfully).

```
check_branch:
    if [ "$$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" == "master" ]; then \
    ...
```

Answer (score 6):

In shell lines, you write shell commands as you would in a shell script. That's why the second operation works.

If you want Make to evaluate git command outside of the shell, you can enclose the operation in a shell function, as in:

```
$(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

And you ought to be good to go, though I often implement this kind of thing as:

```
branch := $(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
target:dep
     mkdir -p build/$(branch)
```

Or something along those lines.