# Simple echo in makefile escape issue

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

this is a really simple issue, but I am struggling to figure out how to do it. I have a makefile, and in the make file I have the following line:

```
echo "java packet.Program $1 $2 $3 $4" > programScript
```

My question is this: How do I make this line print exactly what is in the quotes? Right now, it keeps trying to interpret $1, $2, $3, $4 as parameters. I want the makefile, when run, to echo exactly "java packet.Program $1 $2 $3 $4" char for char. The '$' are giving me an issue.

Thanks.

Edit:

To clarify the issue. When I type "echo 'java packet.Program $1 $2 $3 $4' > programScript" into the terminal, it prints it exactly how it should. But when I put the same line into my makefile file, and run "make", it doesnt print anything after "java packet.Program".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make` does not attempt to parse command lines, so `"$name"` and `'$name'` are treated the same by `make`; in both cases, the `$name` will be substituted with the value of the `make` variable `$(name)`. In neither case will the shell see the `$`.

If you want to insert a literal `$` in a command in a makefile, you need to write `$$`.

So, for example:

```
show_a_dollar:
        echo '$$a'

show_a_variable:
        echo "$$a"
```

In the first `make` rule, the resulting action is:

```
echo '$a'
```

which will echo, literally, `$a`. In the second, the resulting action is

```
echo "$a"
```

which will echo the value of the environment variable `a`.

So you need to consider *both* `make` expansion rules, which require you to double the `$` to `$$`, and shell expansion rules, which require the command-line argument to be within single-quotes:

```
echo 'java packet.Program $$1 $$2 $$3 $$4' > programScript
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$$` to echo a $ in a Makefile.
Reference:
[Escaping in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382764/escaping-in-makefile)

Comment: I think this is more of an issue with the makefile formatting, then it is with echo formatting. I tried using the single quotes, and when I run make, nothing gets printed after "java packet.Program"

Comment: My issue is: Using single quotes in the terminal prints it exactly how I want it. But when I put the same line into the makefile file, and run "make", it doesn't print the "$1" parts

Answer (score 0):

Use either single quote

```
echo 'java packet.Program $1 $2 $3 $4' > programScript
```

Or, escape them:

```
echo "java packet.Program \$1 \$2 \$3 \$4" > programScript
```

Comment: My issue is: Using single quotes in the terminal prints it exactly how I want it. But when I put the same line into the makefile file, and run "make", it doesn't print anything after "java packet.Program", so none of the "$1"