# Why doesn't my Makefile interpolate an expression in a command

Tags: go, makefile

I'm trying to write a super simple `Makefile` to run the tests in a Go project. The project's dependencies are vendored, but I want to skip these tests. When running this from the command line I simply do

```
$ go test $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
```

Yet, when I put this into a `Makefile` like this:

```
test:
    go test $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)

.PHONY: test
```

the expression will not be evaluated:

```
$ make
go test 
?       github.com/m90/some-repo    [no test files]
```

How do I get make to interpolate the expression in a shell-like manner?

Comment: note that in go1.9 this will no longer be necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382764/escaping-in-makefile)

Comment: FWIW: Godo is a super useful replacement for make for Go projects: https://github.com/go-godo/godo

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a Makefile recipe section you will need to escape the `$` using a second `$`:

```
test:
    go test $$(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)

.PHONY: test
```

Comment: That's correct, but it's not secondary expansion. It's escaping the special character.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the circumstance, it might be more useful to evaluate the command during the expansion of the recipe using [shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function) function:

```
test:
    go test $(shell go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)

.PHONY: test
```

This will make the package names part of the recipe, and will normally print the result of the subcommand when executed.