# Recipe for target 'all' failed: Makefile error

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-device-driver

Following is my makefile for a device driver I'm writing and when I try to `make` it gives me the error:

> recipe for target 'all' failed. error: *** /lib/modules/build/ : No
>   such file or directory

**makefile** :

```
obj-m+=myDevice.o

all:
 make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules
 $(CC) testDevice.c -o test
clean:
 make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) clean
 rm test
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't my Makefile interpolate an expression in a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167230/why-doesnt-my-makefile-interpolate-an-expression-in-a-command)

Comment: Try `$(shell uname -r)`

Comment: @Beta `$$(uname -r)` is even better on the performance point of view: it saves one shell invocation.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: Good point.