# Find and merge all package.json files into one using jq in bash?

Tags: json, node.js, bash, jq

How can I find all `package.json` files and merge them into one file using `jq` within Bash?  The following snippet is as far as I have gotten, however it **appends** the files:

```
find ../../projects -maxdepth 4 -type f -name "package.json" \
  -exec cat {} + | jq -s . > $(CURDIR)/node/.tmp/package.json
```

I have tried using 'add' but that seems to overwrite the target each time without merging the two.

My project structure **initially** looks like this:

```
\ projects
  \ webapp
     \ package.json
  \ service
     \ package.json
  \ admin
     \ package.json
\ solutions
  \ killersolution
       Makefile
     \ node
```

And **should** look like this after `make prenode` (see below):

```
\ projects
  \ webapp
     \ package.json
  \ service
     \ package.json
  \ admin
     \ package.json
\ solutions
  \ killersolution
       Makefile
     \ node
        \ .tmp
          \ package.json   <- created
```

I am using a `Makefile` to kick this off:

```
prenode:                                                                 
  @find ./node -type d -name ".tmp" -exec rm -rf {} +;                 
  @mkdir -p ./node/.tmp                                                
  @find ../../solutions -maxdepth 4 -type f -name "package.json" -exec cat {} + ...
```

**Edit #1 : Example Input & Output**
Let us assume 3 `package.json` files were found.  The `dependencies` and `devDependencies` are different but must be combined:

Found file #1 ...

```
{
  "name":"project-a",
  "dependencies":{
    "module-a":"1.2.3"
  }
}
```

Found file #2 ...

```
{
  "name":"project-b",
  "dependencies":{
    "module-b":"2.3.4"
  }
}
```

Found file #3 ...

```
{
  "name":"project-c",
  "devDependencies":{
    "gulp":"*"
  }
}
```

... would all be combined to make the following file:

```
{
  "name":"project-c",
  "dependencies":{
    "module-a":"1.2.3",
    "module-b":"2.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies":{
    "gulp":"*"
  }
}
```

*Note: 
The `name` property, in the final output file, is irrelevant.  The key here is the merge of the `dependencies` and `devDependencies` objects.

Comment: Please give an example of your desired output

Comment: @hek2mgl My pleasure.  I've updated the question to show example source files and the desired output.

Comment: What should happen with the `author` entry, for example? Take all scalars from project-c?

Comment: @hek2mgl doesn't matter ... i assume the entry would be created if it doesn't already exist ... no need to check for equality

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following find command works for you (adjust if necessary)

```
find ../../projects -name package.json
```

Here is a solution which uses the jq **`*`** operator along with **reduce** and the `-s` option to merge the objects:

```
jq -s 'reduce .[] as $d ({}; . *= $d)' $(find ../../projects -name package.json)
```

If you prefer you can just as easily concatenate the files and send them to jq

```
find ../../projects -name package.json -exec cat {} \; | \
  jq -M -s 'reduce .[] as $d ({}; . *= $d)'
```

As noted in my reply to your comment if you're doing this in a makefile you need to take extra steps to deal with the $ or put your filter in a file and use `-f`

Comment: I tried a similar syntax to this and was running into errors using `make` with it.

Comment: In a makefile you may need to double the $'s.  e.g. `
foo:
 jq -s 'reduce .[] as $$d ({}; . *= $$d)' $$(find ../../projects -name package.json)` or place your filter in a file and use the jq `-f` option

Comment: Re: `$` in makefiles, see the answer to this question: [Escaping in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2382810/8379597)

Answer (score 1):

If your jq has `inputs`, here is a more efficient solution than is possible using the -s ("slurp") option:

```
reduce inputs as $i ({};
  .dependencies += ($i | .dependencies )
  | .devDependencies += ($i | .devDependencies ) )
```

This also produces a "clean" result (i.e., no "name" field).

Remember to use the -n command-line option with `inputs`, e.g. along the lines of:

```
jq -n -f program.jq $(find ...)
```

#### reduce-free solution

In case your jq does not have `inputs`, here is a reduce-free solution when used with the "-s" command-line option:

```
map([.dependencies, .devDependencies])
| transpose
| map(add)
| {dependencies: .[0], devDependencies: .[1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an FYI for anyone who needs it now, I **am** currently doing this using `xargs` and a utility called [`package-utils`](https://github.com/tcurdt/package-utils).  The `jq` thing was more of a *want* than anything.

Here's the current makefile, if you'd like to use it:

```
prenode:
  @find $(CURDIR)/node -type d -name ".tmp" -exec rm -rf {} +;
  @mkdir -p $(CURDIR)/node/.tmp
  @find ../../projects -type f -name "package.json" -maxdepth 4 -print0 | xargs -0 package-merge > $(CURDIR)/node/.tmp/package.json
```

My overall goal with this is for use within Docker and Docker Compose.  I am using it to pre-cache all of the NPM modules, used within a single solution, in a base image.  Basically, it creates a temporary `package.json` file that is used during the build process.

Within my `Dockerfile` is the following:

```
COPY ./.tmp/package.json /var/www/package.json

VOLUME /var/www
VOLUME /var/www/node_modules

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN npm install
RUN rm package.json
```

This allows the Node cache to be populated so any container based on this image will be able to install mostly everything from the cache.

There **is** a reason I'm doing this instead of a common volume for `node_modules` but that's a different story.