# what is the purpose of head, cat and awk in GNU makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I am new to Linux and trying to understand the function of following makefile syntax. I know about different commands like head or awk but could not make out what will be the effect of the following script.

head -c $$((0x100)) /dev/zero | cat - $< | xxd -g1 -c4 | awk '{print $$5$$4$$3$$2}' > $@

A detailed explanation of commands along with switches will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `$$((0x100))` means, "`256`.. but I get paid by the character!".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two dollars are just [one escaped dollar sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382764/escaping-in-makefile).

So:

```
head -c $((0x100)) /dev/zero
```

`0x100` is "256" so this is getting the first 256 bytes from `/dev/zero` which [produces and endless stream of NULL characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63238/purpose-of-dev-zero) `0x00`

That is then cat'd together with the [first prerequisite.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116547/what-do-and-in-a-makefile-mean) `-` is the stdin that was piped and `$<` is explained in that link, but it's a makefile thing, not a linux/shell thing)

```
 cat - $<
```

Which is then piped to xxd

```
xxd -g1 -c4
```

which will output the results of the `cat` as hex with 1 bit (`-g1`) separating octets, and 4 octets per line (`-c4`). I would imagine the separator here is in place so awk can do it's thing.

Which is then piped to awk

```
awk '{print $5$4$3$2}' > $@
```

to print columns 5, 4, 3, and 2 in that order with no characters between them and redirecting the stdout to the `$@` [filename of the target rule](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116547/what-do-and-in-a-makefile-mean) which is also another makefile thing, not a linux/shell thing

I have no idea why though.