# increase value of returned value by 1 with makefile script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile, sh

i've return number with the following format

```
v0.0.1
```

so in this case I need to change the number to

```
v0.0.2
```

if I got

```
v0.0.9
```

I want to change it to

```
v0.1.0
```

and so own...each time increase with one

what I've tried is the following

```
awk -F. '{$NF+=1; OFS="."; print $0}
```

which doesn't work(give the same value), what could be the problem ?

I use before `VERSION=git describe --tags --abbrev=0 | awk -F. '{$NF+=1; OFS="."; print $0}'`

which doesnt works...

**update**

When I try the code of james I got the value increased without the `dots` and without the `v`

[image]

Comment: Why do you want `0.0.9 -> 0.1.0` instead of `0.0.9 -> 0.0.10`?

Comment: In case you want to `semverbump` https://github.com/nbari/semverbump

Comment: Version numbers are not floating-point numbers; they are dotted strings with integer fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A play with the separators and record rebuilding:

```
$ echo 0.0.9 | 
awk '
BEGIN {
    FS="."                  # set the separators
    OFS=""
}
{
    sub(/^v/,"")            # remove the v
    $1=$1                   # rebuild record to remove periods
    $0=sprintf("%03d",$0+1) # zeropad the number after adding 1 to it
}
END {
    FS=""                   # reset the separators 
    OFS="."
    $0=$0                   # this to keep the value in $0
    $1=$1                   # rebuild to get the periods back
    print "v" $0            # output
}'
v0.1.0
```

Seemed to work with 9.9.9 -> 1.0.0.0.

Comment: This is a neat answer. Can you give a short explanation?

Comment: Can you please show how should the makfile should look ? I want to test it and Im not too expert with makfiles etc

Comment: I haven't touched a makefile in 20 years. :D They still `make` them? :D :D

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that one. I'd need to get my K&R and that would make my table unstable.

Comment: Would this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382764/escaping-in-makefile ?

Comment: @JamesBrown - the whole code should be like this, `VERSION=`git describe --tags --abbrev=0 | awk -F. '{$NF+=1; OFS="."; print $0}'`` but didnt able to make it work , I think I missed some sperators ,can you have a look please?

Comment: How should I use your code with the `VERSION=git describe --tags --abbrev=0 |` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168407/discussion-between-nina-watcher-and-james-brown).

Comment: @JamesBrown - please see my update, does it give you any clue ? even if I try it in the cli I got the wrong output ....any idea ?

Comment: Added lines to remove the v and to put it back.

Comment: Now I was able to get the version but it still v010 when I try the updated script ..., are you getting v.0.1.0 ? anyhow I'll close the question and open new one, maybe someone have idea ...thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The minor problem is `OFS` needs to be set before you increase the column. The worse problem is you don't handle the case for 9 (0.0.9->0.1.0):

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F. '{OFS="."; 
    printf("v");
    for(i=NF; i>0;i--) {
        $i++;
        if ($i<10) break;
        if(i>1) $i=0;
    }
}1'
```

This can be a one liner, I just put it in a script for readability. You would use it:

```
echo 9.9.9 | myscript.bash
```

Another problem is overflow, handled by the `if(i>1)`. Note the input cannot contain a `v`. If you have in `bash` `VERSION=v1.2.3`, you can easily get the relevant substring with `${VERSION:1}`.

Comment: Thanks Im using make file should I adjust it ? I want to try it with make and I got error `makefile:3: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.`

Comment: I don't know how you're running your `Makefile`. If what you had before worked, you can just replace the line you had with my answer (without the #! line, just put everything on a single line).

Comment: `awk -F. '{OFS="."; for(i=NF; i>0;i--) { $i++; if ($i<10) break; if(i>1) $i=0; } }1'`

Comment: Can you please update the answer with the example with the makefile ?

Comment: That's a question on Makefiles. If this solved your `awk` question, mark this accepted, then ask a proper question (after research) on how to put commands in `Makefile`s.

Comment: You can link it here and I'll have a look later.

Comment: I dont know how to test it, I just want run it with new makefile to see that it works and then I'll integrate it with the orig makfile...

Answer (score 2):

Well, in a bash function, what about this?

```
$ function incv { printf "%03d\n" $((10#${1//[^0-9]/}+1)) | sed -E 's/(.)(.)(.)/v\1.\2.\3/'; }
$ incv v0.0.9
v0.1.0
$ incv v0.1.5
v0.1.6
```

The idea here is:

1. we remove non-digits and treat the number like a normal base 10 number,
2. we increment the number, and
3. we print the number as a zero-padded 3 digit number, with reformatting by sed.

We could do the sed part in bash alone, but it would be more work....

I think the only weird part of this is the `10#`. Its purpose is to ensure that the number is interpreted as base 10, since a leading 0 might otherwise cause bash to consider the number to be octal. Which wouldn't work for `v0.0.9`. :)

Comment: Thanks but I need to check it with make file, can it be adopted to makefile please ?\

Comment: I don't see anything about that in your question. The function I've provided is a working alternative to the code attempt you provided. Can you please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49691371/edit) with your actual requirements?

Comment: thanks, i've updated the question :) btw I've put it with tag of makefile when I opend the question  :)

Comment: @Ninawatcher, I still don't see anything in the question that is about Makefiles. The text "with makefile script" in the subject isn't enough. What is it that you're trying to do with a Makefile? Put an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question to make it absolutely clear what you're doing. As it is, your question only contains code that attempts to increment a version number, which is why all the answers you've received show you .. how to increment a version number.

Comment: The code before was `VERSION=`git describe --tags --abbrev=0 | awk -F. '{$NF+=1; OFS="."; print $0}'`which doesnt work, how can I change it to use your code to test it , can you please assist ?

Comment: @Ninawatcher, comments are terrible for formatting. If it's relevant to your question, it should be in your question.

Comment: Done please have a look :)

Answer (score 1):

pure **bash**, on @ghoti solution

```
#!/bin/bash

increase_version(){
    local string display c

    string=$((10#${1//[^0-9]}+1))
    string=$(printf "%03d\n" "$string" )
    for (( c=0; c < ${#string}; c++ )); do
        display+="${string:$c:1}."
    done
    echo "v${display::-1}"
}

echo -n "v0.0.1  ->  " ; increase_version "v0.0.1"
echo -n "v0.0.9  ->  " ; increase_version "v0.0.9"

echo -e "\nbash $BASH_VERSION"
```

**output**

```
v0.0.1  ->  v0.0.2
v0.0.9  ->  v0.1.0

bash 4.4.18(1)-release
```

**bench**

loop with 10000 iterations:

- bash only: 8972 ms
- with sed: 16020 ms
- with awk: 24830 ms (script @JamesBrown)

the execution time is not the only standard of quality, I publish it for information

Comment: Btw, when I try to run the script you provided I got error `v0.0.1  ->  ./bs.sh: line 11: -1: substring expression < 0
v0.0.9  ->  ./bs.sh: line 11: -1: substring expression < 0

bash 3.2.57(1)-release`

Comment: any idea why this happen ? I use mac...and I did `chmod +x`

Comment: sorry, I don't know why. You use bash 3.2,, but with compat32, il works for me :/ I assume the error is on `echo "v${display::-1}"`? Can you test with `echo "v${display:0:-1}"` or `echo "v${display%\.}"`