# Bash command id in my Makefile not working

Tags: linux, shell, makefile

How do you do to get your UID on Makefile. I use `id -u` in my prompt and thats return my UID withou problem but in my Makefile

```
perm-user:
    @echo $(id -u)
```

That's return nothing. Someone have a idea ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Also see [Escaping in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2382764/608639)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Escape the `$` so the shell interprets it rather than make.

```
@echo $$(id -u)
```

There's no need for the `echo`, though. `echo $(cmd)` is the same as `cmd`.

```
@id -u
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will use this in other command that's why the echo