# How to write dollar symbol ($) using sed stream editor

Tags: regex, sed, terminal

I'm trying to append a new dynamic line in file using '**sed**'  but can't be able to write **'$'** symbol

Please not that I'm using **sed** from inside Makefile

I'm trying some thing like:

```
sed -i '1 i\export PATH := tools/bin/linux/x64:\$\(PATH\)' $(DEST_DIR)/Makefile
```

I expect following output of above command

```
export PATH := tools/bin/linux/x64:$(PATH)
```

But instead I get following output

```
export PATH := tools/bin/linux/x64:(PATH)
```

How can I get **$** in my output.

Comment: @BlackMamba yes I tried but same result

Comment: @anubhava because of I'm using sed from inside the makefile,  your suggestion expand the $(PATH) variable.

Comment: ok try `sed '1 i\export PATH := tools/bin/linux/x64:$$(PATH)'` (2 `$` signs and single quotes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382764/escaping-in-makefile)

Comment: @anubhava thanks it is working.  You can write this is an answer.

Comment: Please accept the duplicate nomination instead. This is a common FAQ; having more answers to it is not better.

Comment: Why are you putting a Makefile in $(DESTDIR)?  This is a broken package!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For using `sed` inside the `Makefile` use:

```
sed '1 i\export PATH := tools/bin/linux/x64:$$(PATH)' $(DEST_DIR)/Makefile
```

That is 2 `$` signs and all of `sed` command in single quotes.