# Using makefile to download a file from AWS to local

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-s3, makefile, gnu-make

I want to set up a target which downloads the latest s3 file containing `_id_config` within a path. So I know I can get the name of file I am interested in by

```
FILE=$(shell aws s3 ls s3:blah//xyz/mno/here  --recursive | sort | tail -n 2 | awk '{print $4}' | grep id_config)
```

Now, I want to download the file to local with something like

```
download_stuff:
    aws s3 cp s3://prod_an.live.data/$FILE .
```

But when I run this, my $FILE has some extra stuff like

```
aws s3 cp s3://blah/2022-02-17 16:02:21    2098880 blah//xyz/mno/here54fa8c68e41_id_config.json . 

Unknown options: 2098880,blah/xyz/mno/here54fa8c68e41_id_config.json,.
```

Please can someone help me understand why `2098880` and the spaces are there in the output and how to resolve this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: See [escaping in a makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382764/escaping-in-makefile), you need to escape the `$` with `$$`, or do something like `shell aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket "blah" --prefix "xyz/mno/here" | jq -r '.Contents[].Key' | sort | grep id_config | tail -1` to properly handle some edge cases with spaces in keys.

Comment: You should really use `:=` not `=` when assigning the value to the `FILE` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting a trick with `ls` options `-1` and `-t` to get the latest files in a folder:

```
FILE=$(shell aws s3 ls -1t s3:blah//xyz/mno/here  |head -n 2 | grep id_config)
```

Comment: That won't work, `aws s3 ls` is not the same as `ls`

Comment: sorry to hear that, give us some examples of ` aws s3 ls` output. So that we can test `awk` or `sed` on it.

Comment: Why?  Then you'd have the awk command the original question started with.

Comment: If you want assistance give us some sample input to work with.

Comment: I don't want any assistance, I'm trying to help you.